# Sagemaker Pytorch : Cant import sklearn from training script

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker

I am running a pytorch model in sagemaker

```
from sagemaker.pytorch import PyTorch

estimator = PyTorch(entry_point='train.py',
                    role=role,
                    framework_version='1.0.0',
                    train_instance_count=1,
                    train_instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge',
                    source_dir='source', #the directory where the supporting files are

                    #what is passed in
                    hyperparameters={
                        'max_epochs' : 6,
                        'layer_dim'  : "2500,500,100,1",
                        'batch_size' : 64,
                        'seed'       : 4524,
                        'cuda'       : False
                        }
                   )
```

where the entry script train.py includes several imports

```
import argparse
import math
import os
from shutil import copy
import time
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
```

But the sklearn call fails:

```
  File "/opt/ml/code/train.py", line 9, in <module>
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

Questions:

1. How do I use sklearn functions in this case?
2. Can you add additional pip installs without going the custom docker route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can install dependencies without going the custom dockerfile route (also BYO Container)

Use this in your code (where `mypackage` represents a pip package of your choice)

```
import subprocess as sb 
import sys 

sb.call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", mypackage])
```

Comment: This is great! Can I ask a follow-up. Lets say we use scikit to build a standardscalar and fit and apply it during training. Can the transformer be saved to the model directory and then accessed in a customer predict_fn function?

Comment: yes, when you use custom code you can add anything to the model_dir and re-use it later. Note the Inference Pipeline feature that enables to deploy a sequence of collocated containers, that can typically be a pre-processing container followed by an inference container: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/inference-pipelines.html  https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/scikit_learn_inference_pipeline/Inference%20Pipeline%20with%20Scikit-learn%20and%20Linear%20Learner.ipynb